# How to initialize a multi-line array at the PowerShell prompt (not in a script)?

Tags: powershell, prompt

I'd like to initialize this array at the PowerShell prompt:

```
$Parameters = @{
    SourcePath = 'D:\Website'
    TargetPath = 'wwwroot'
    ComputerName 'https://website:8172/msdeploy.axd?site=website'
    Credential = $Credential
}
```

However, when I paste this command I'm prevented by a series of symbols from pressing `Enter` to get back to the prompt:

[image: Blocked]

Pressing `Enter` only generates a new line with another set of symbols.

Is this possible to do at the prompt (not in a script)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the PowerShell command prompt, if the line-continuation prompt **`>>`  keeps appearing when you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the implication is that the command is syntactically *incomplete* or *broken*.**

<sup>Note: If module `PSReadLine`, which ships with W10, is imported, a command is recognized as complete right away; without it, an *extra* <kbd>Enter</kbd> keypress is needed.</sup>

Therefore, **if you expect the command to be complete, yet `>>`  keeps appearing, the implication is that the command contains a *syntax error***, which is indeed what happened in your case, as you've discovered:
Line `ComputerName 'https://website:8172/msdeploy.axd?site=website'`, meant to be a hashtable's key-value pair definition, was missing the `=` between key `ComputerName` and value `'https://website:8172/msdeploy.axd?site=website'`.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed as soon as I posted this that I was missing the `=` in the third element (`ComputerName`).

Fixing that solved the problem.

Comment: Glad to hear you found a solution (as an aside: you're not defining an _array_, you're defining a _hash table_). Given that your problem was the result of a simple typo - which is one of the standard reasons for closing a question - can I suggest you delete your question?

Comment: @mklement0: I thought about deleting it, but then I wanted to leave it so others having the same problem might be able to use it. What do you think?

Comment: Please see my answer, which aims to be more general - perhaps as such it is useful to future readers.

Comment: @mklement0: Good job, thanks. (Especially the tip about `PSReadLine`.)